# Restore typeahead in Nautilus (UbuntuGNOME)

Tags: gnome, nautilus, ubuntu-gnome

In the default version of Nautilus that UbuntuGNOME comes with, when you begin typing in a folder, instead of selecting the first matching file, Nautilus executes a full search of all subdirectories. The search is laggy, and moreover is not what most users are accustomed to happening. In the default Unity-based Ubuntu 14.04, the old behavior ("typeahead") [has been restored](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/ubuntu-14-04-nautilus-type-ahead-patch) through a patch to Nautilus.

Is there a way to patch Nautilus in UbuntuGNOME to restore "typeahead" functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Execute the following command in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) to enable the typeahead feature in Ubuntu GNOME:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search true
```

This is set to `false` in Ubuntu GNOME by default, but set to `true` in Unity, which enables the type-ahead functionality in it.

Comment: This no longer works for Nautilus 3.20 :<

Comment: The option has been removed in 3.26, which is the current version in Ubuntu 17.10  http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-17-10-to-ship-with-nautilus-3-24-file-manager-without-type-ahead-search-513211.shtml

Comment: Here's a bug discussing this issue. Make your voice heard. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/244